# Why was SPYRAL Quik Fix limited instead of banned?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

> When this card is normal or special summoned, you can add 1 SPYRAL Gear card from your deck to your hand. If this card is in your graveyard, you can discard 1 card to special this card, but banish it when it leaves the field.

Konami "fixed" this card by limiting it to 1. Even if you're lucky enough to draw an Effect Veiler, Ash Blossom, or a Ghost Ogre before the player can use his effect, they can just use it's effect multiple times. Even then you still have a problem, Ghost Ogre may destroy it, but it still gets to activate it's effect and can just add SPYRAL Gear - Big Red to bring it back. And Ash Blossom or Effect Veiler may stop it from searching, but it doesn't destroy it. So someone can still do damage with it. And if you aren't lucky enough to draw those cards, it basically will most likely end in a OTK. And trust me. I've dueled enough SPYRAL decks to know how easy that one card can make it to win in 1 turn.

And also even if someone doesn't start out with it in their hand. It's easy to search for. They can search it with SPYRAL Resort, SPYRAL Master Plan, etc. Or you can special summon it with it's own effect, SPYRAL MISSION - Rescue, SPYRAL Gear - Big Red, etc.

So with this in mind. Why has this card been limited rather than banned?

Answer (score 3):

> Why has this card been limited rather than banned?

Konami **rarely bans a card directly after it being unrestricted**. Usually they gradually restrict cards: first semi-limit, then limit, and if it is still Overpowered then they ban it.

For that to happen the card has to be *really* broken or well be some key resource that Top Championship Decks abuse of (as to balance the format).

Another reason is that **Konami usually lets their new archetypes "live" longer before nerfing them**. SPYRAL archetype is rather recent to date, so they probably don't want to kill it when many competitive players are still investing heavily on those decks (an economic move if you ask me).

Banning that card would heavily affect all SPYRAL decks, therefore strongly affecting many players throughout the world as well as notably changing the balance of the current format.

Surely there must be other reasons they did this, but those are probably internal to the company and not something they openly share.

Comment: I guess that's fair enough. but even limiting this card hasn't fixed a thing. It's still a broken card.

Comment: @Therationalduelist probably will get banned next banlist if that is so, or when new archetypes come out

Comment: It doesn't need to be banned. It's effect needs to be limited to once per turn. Like for example. My Blue Eyes is my favorite deck, but I also really love my Magnet Warriors, and the best ones are the Electromagnet warriors. They're like different versions of Quik Fix. Beta when summoned allows me to add 1 level 4 or lower magnet warrior to my hand. Gamma when summoned let's me special another one from my hand. And Alpha let's me add a level 8 Magna warrior to my hand when summoned. They're strong, but at least they're limited to once a turn. Quick Fix isn't. If he was, it wouldn't be broken.

Comment: @Therationalduelist good points, surely that change could sound reasonable. I also consider that it is more likely that a card is limited,semilimited,etc., than it to be rewritten. Rewriting is usually done when they really screw up with the text.

Comment: I guess so. But I'm really getting sick of this card making it so easy for an OTK. I'll figure out a way to keep it off the field. I'm working on a Galaxy Eyes Deck. And there's a really handy card called "Photon Stream of Destruction." This quick play spell allows me to remove one card on my opponent's side of the field from the game, but however, I can only activate it during my opponent's turn when I control Galaxy Eyes Photon Dragon.

Comment: @Therationalduelist have you seen [Mistake](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Mistake)? That could stop the searching eff of that card. You can also try with effect veiler or similar, always comes in handy, and can even help to synchro (plus it is light and surely could go well with Galaxy Eyes decks)

Comment: I haven't forgotten that one time that Mistake was used to slow me down with my Max Dragon